# iTunes error (err = -3259) after downloading iOS 4.3.3

Tags: windows-xp, itunes

I receive an iTunes error (err = -3259) after I download iOS 4.3.3. I am using Windows XP. I just installed the latest iTunes and my security suite is configured to allow iTunes.

I have seen suggestions that advised disabling my firewall, so I *may* try that.

If it is the firewall that is causing this issue, should not the error show *before* downloading a 650 MB file, and not after three hours of downloading said file?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into this error and was never able to resolve it. Later I used the following steps as a workaround to upgrade iOS (or only download it if that is what you want).

Download iOS from a third party site. I use the site [felixbruns](http://www.felixbruns.de/iPod/firmware/). They've got all the versions for respective devices.

On iTunes, you have a restore button. Hold 'shift' and click 'restore'. You will now get an option to navigate to the iOS file (*.ipsw) that was downloaded. Navigate to it > select and open. The iOS on the device will now upgrade itself.

By restoring iOS firmware, all content on the device will be erased and will be reset to factory settings. Make sure to backup before restoring the iOS firmware.

---

You can also try what is mentioned in the apple knowledge base article [TS2799](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS2799?viewlocale=en_US).

Comment: Wow, thanks I'll try this. I'm actually trying to find a different source but thanks for the site. And by backup, that means right clicking on the device in iTunes, and click backup, right?

Comment: Backup means having a copy of all the content of your device (apps, movies, music, books etc:) on another location like an external hard disk. Because once you go through with this, your device will be as good as new.

Comment: Yep, I got it, restoring now. It worked man, thanks a lot, really. :)